# Request Data Not Passed From View To Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view That Posts data as follows (image from fiddler request)
[Request Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrIa1.png)

and I am accepting it in the action as follows :

```
public ActionResult AddProblem(Problem newproblem, string submit)
{
            //  Validating Saving the problem in the database 
            // part of it as follows
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                decimal TotalValue = 0M;
                foreach (var req in newproblem.Requireds) // This Line Throws a Null Reference Only in Production
                {
                    TotalValue += req.Value;
                }
            // rest of the code 
}
```

I am testing locally and everything is fine yet the published code gives me a null reference exception when I access the Requireds in the model passed from the view

my models are like this

```
    public class Problem
    {
        public Problem()
        {
            generalInformation = new GeneralQuestion();
            Requireds = new List<ProblemRequired>();
        }
        public GeneralQuestion generalInformation { get; set; }
        public List<ProblemRequired> Requireds { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Problem Text")]
        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalMark { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProblemRequired
    {
        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SolutionKey { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Question Mark")]
        [Range(0.01, 100.00, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a correct mark")]
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public decimal CorrectAnswer  { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CorrectNotation { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Unit { get; set; }
    }
```

Any Idea Why is the data not passed to the action method only in production ?

Comment: What the error do you have? Did  you check the browser developer tools ?

Comment: After turning the custom error mode to off, Its a NullReferenceException in the line I mentioned above 
about the developers tools nothing is unusual

Comment: But the picture shows that requires are not null.  i think newproblem is null. Did you check in debugger?

Comment: Locally everything is correct while in the server it gives the error

Comment: What about  a TotalValue ? I don't that it is assigned

Comment: Its assigned to 0 and the value of each required should be added to it

Comment: I tried a post with no requireds at all and it returned to view with no errors (just a message to enter at least one required)

Comment: A few common issues 1) When publishing the executable comes from the Release folder in your project.  Sometime you ony build the debug version.  So check dates in bin folder to see that both the executable in the build and release foldre are current 2) On a server you do not have the same credentials as local.3) Your connection string may not work on the server.  Check the connection string.

Comment: Most of these issues are general not specific to a small portion of the project yet
1) I am sure that I build the release version
2) I am sure of having the right credentials
3) I am sure of the connection string

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your "View page" I'm guessing you are not binding the request body.  try these changes.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("AddProblem")]
public ActionResult AddProblem([FromBody]Problem newproblem, string submit)
```